# https headers with file_get_contents

Tags: php

This does not get gzipped content, but plain content. How to make file_get_contents send headers with https ?

```
$url = 'https://www.google.co.in/';

///Try to fetch compressed content using the file_get_contents function
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n" .
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n" .
                "Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5\r\n"
)
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$zipped_content = file_get_contents($url ,false,$context);

echo $zipped_content;

print_r($http_response_header);
```

If the url is http://www.yahoo.co.in then the gzipped content is served (and to confirm, it appears like rubbish).

But when using "https://" it seems that file_get_contents does not send the headers specified.

Comment: You probably need to use `fread` instead, which is binary-safe. `file_get_contents` loads the data as a string... not really what you're looking for.

Comment: Check headers that your browser send to google and try to send them all.

Comment: @sectus headers are all ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header are no OK... Add User-agent and it will be fine.

```
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0 FirePHP/0.4\r\n".
```

Why? Google decides.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $url = "https://www.google.co.in/";   
  $ch = curl_init();    
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);   
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);   
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);    
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Encoding: gzip'));   
  $contents = curl_exec($ch);   
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: i need the gzipped content, that curl code will fetch me the final html contents of the page which i dont need.